# What's the biggest hurdle that prevents the EPA from implementing stricter limits on particulate matter?

Tags: united-states, environmental-policy

> Voters want the EPA to listen to its scientific advisors and implement
> even stricter limits on particulate matter. When we asked Pennsylvania
> voters if they support or oppose stricter limits on “fine particles,
> also called soot” on BOTH an annual and daily basis (see table below
> for the full language of the question), 78% support the stricter
> standards.

https://action.lung.org/site/DocServer/ALA_Particulate_Matter_PA_Memo.pdf

What's the biggest hurdle that prevents the EPA from implementing stricter limits on particulate matter? It seems that implementing stricter limits on particulate matter is an overwhelming popular policy that's supported by a majority of people and across partisan lines, so what's preventing the EPA from doing so. Is there any political hurdle the EPA or the government must overcome in order to enact this into law?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The basic law about how regulations are created is the [Administrative Procedures Act](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Administrative_Procedure_Act). This lays down the procedure that the US government must go through to ensure that the rules it makes are effective and proportionate.

The EPA's page on its implementation of this act is here: https://www.epa.gov/laws-regulations/basics-regulatory-process

The EPA is authorised to set limits on air pollution by the [Clean Air Act](https://www.epa.gov/laws-regulations/summary-clean-air-act), so all it needs to do is to set the consultation process in motion.

However, politics.

The EPA is overseen by an Administrator who is appointed by the President. So the general political direction of the EPA is set by the President. If the president's policy is to favour industry then the EPA is likely to relax its rules. If the policy is to favour the environment then the EPA is likely to tighten its standards.

At the same time the EPA is continuously lobbied by many interested parties. Companies lobby for relaxed rules on the grounds of jobs and the economy. Green pressure groups lobby for tighter restrictions on the grounds of public health and environmental protection. Some companies also lobby for tighter restrictions because it makes it harder for competitors to set up business. So its complicated. The memo you cite is just one shot in an ongoing battle between these various pressure groups.

So the biggest obstacle is not so much what the EPA has to do, its how one pressure group can make a case to the EPA which persuades it to get moving.

Answer (score 22):

There is no "hurdle". The report mentioned in the question was published on March 14, 2023. The EPA issued a [Final Rule](https://www.federalregister.gov/documents/2024/03/06/2024-02637/reconsideration-of-the-national-ambient-air-quality-standards-for-particulate-matter) on March 6, 2024, reducing particulate matter. The rule is effective as of May 6, 2024.

> Based on the Environmental Protection Agency's (EPA's) reconsideration of the air quality criteria and the national ambient air quality standards (NAAQS) for particulate matter (PM), the EPA is revising the primary annual PM<sub>2.5</sub> standard by lowering the level from 12.0 µg/m<sup>3</sup> to 9.0 µg/m<sup>3</sup>.

Answer (score 1):

> **Question:**
>
> What's the biggest hurdle that prevents the EPA from implementing stricter limits on particulate matter?

**What are we talking about?**

**[Inhalable Particulate Matter and Health](https://ww2.arb.ca.gov/resources/inhalable-particulate-matter-and-health)**

Particulate matter are microscopic particles which when they become airborne or are found in water pose health risks and risks in the environment. Particles with a diameter of 10 microns or less.

PM10 to PM2.5 primary sources is burning carbon fuels.  That's industrial emission,  natural gas emissions, and automobile emissions.

**Short Answer**

What is the primary blocker to the EPA from enforcing restrictions on Particulate Matter, who's primary source is carbon emissions?  The corruption of the supreme court.  The EPA has been blocked by the supreme court from regulating carbon emissions overturning 50 years of precedent in how the **[Clean Air Act ( 1970 )](https://www.epa.gov/clean-air-act-overview/evolution-clean-air-act)** has been used.

**Longer Answer**

> **[Particulate Matter Basics](https://www.epa.gov/pm-pollution/particulate-matter-pm-basics)**
>
> Most particles form in the atmosphere as a result of complex reactions of chemicals such as sulfur dioxide and nitrogen oxides, which are pollutants emitted from power plants, industries and automobiles.

The supreme court has been actively weakening and eliminating the EPA's ability to regulate the nations clean air laws specifically with regard to carbon emissions. Last year they restricted the EPA's ability to enforce carbon emission laws passed by congress the 1970 Clean Air Act.  Another big decision on the EPA's ability to enforce Ozone restrictions is expected to go against the EPA in the next few weeks also having to do with Particulate Matter.  Both directly impacting not just the EPA but the governments ability to enforce laws on particulate matter emissions which have been on the books for 50 years +.

In July of 2022 the Supreme court issued a ruling which overturned 50 years of precedent and limited the EPA's ability to regulate carbon emissions.

- 2022

**[Supreme Court restricts the EPA's authority to mandate carbon emissions reductions](https://www.npr.org/2022/06/30/1103595898/supreme-court-epa-climate-change)**

- 2023

**[The U.S. Supreme Court on Wednesday said it would hear a bid to block the Environmental Protection Agency from enforcing a federal regulation aimed at reducing ozone emissions that may worsen air pollution in neighboring states.](https://www.reuters.com/world/us/us-supreme-court-hear-challenge-epas-good-neighbor-air-pollution-plan-2023-12-20/)**

- 2024

---

**On the Corruption of the supreme court**

> 2024 **[The League of Conservative Voters](https://www.lcv.org/blog/a-relentless-power-grab-scotus-poised-to-weaken-epa-and-other-federal-agencies-in-upcoming-cases-relentless-and-loper-bright/)**
> **A Relentless Power Grab: SCOTUS Poised to Weaken EPA and Other Federal Agencies in Upcoming Cases Relentless and Loper Bright**
>
> On the heels of major Supreme Court decisions to roll back EPA authority on climate and clean water, SCOTUS will hear a new pair of cases that could further gut the power of federal agencies: Relentless, Inc. v. Department of Commerce and Loper Bright Enterprises v. Raimondo.
>
> These cases offer the court’s 6-3 MAGA supermajority another chance to hamstring federal agencies’ authority to protect the people from powerful special interests. Such a ruling would have sweeping implications for environmental law, and would extend to all other areas of public policy, including democracy, healthcare, reproductive rights, labor, immigration, education and more.

**[Ohio v. EPA Threatens the EPA’s Ability To Regulate Air Pollution Nationwide](https://www.americanprogress.org/article/ohio-v-epa-threatens-the-epas-ability-to-regulate-air-pollution-nationwide/)**

> https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UWL4_3QQXLI
>
> The Scheme 29: Fake Facts and “Knight-Errantry” at the Supreme Court
>
> March 6, 2024 | **Senator Sheldon Whitehouse (D-RI), Chairman of the Senate Judiciary Courts Subcommittee**, delivers the twenty-ninth in a series of speeches titled “The Scheme,” exposing the machinations by right-wing donor interests to capture the Supreme Court and achieve through the Court what they cannot through the elected branches of government.
>
> Whitehouse details the findings of his latest law review article, entitled “Knights-Errant: The Roberts Court and Erroneous Fact-Finding.”  Whitehouse’s article sheds light on the Court’s propensity for relying on extra-record – and often false – facts that lend advantage to Republican or corporate special interests.  The article details bogus and uncorrected facts in Supreme Court decisions, explains their consequences in disrupting settled precedents, and explores actions the judicial and legislative branches could take to ensure the Court cleans up factual errors and kicks its fact-finding habit.

The US supreme court is corrupt.  The Majority of Justices on the supreme court have accepted very expensive "gifts" in the forms of trips, private cruses, accommodations, vehicles, and cash from various Billionaires and millionaires with business interests before the court, systemically over decades.  One received a $200,000 dollar vehicle along with millions more in cash and trips.  One sold his family home to a billionaire who invested more than $100,000s to improve the structure, and the Justices mother has continued to live in the home rent free now for decades.   Not bad for a civil servants who makes less than $300,000 a year.

Federal judges are not permitted to accept such extraordinary gifts or cash payments.  The supreme court polices themselves and do not hold themselves to the same standards which apply to all federal judges.

Justice Samual Alito claim their are not checks or balances on the Supreme court.  That Congress doesn't have the authority to regulate the Supreme Court?

- Politico, **[Alito: Congress can’t regulate Supreme Court ethics](https://www.politico.com/news/2023/07/28/alito-congress-supreme-court-ethics-00108830)**
- **[Keeping Up with the (Supreme) Court’s Corruption](https://endcitizensunited.org/latest-news/press-releases/keeping-up-with-the-courts-corruption/)**
- LA Times, **[Supreme Court Justice Clarence Thomas’ corruption is intolerable. Here’s what we can do about it](https://www.latimes.com/opinion/story/2023-08-10/supreme-court-justice-clarence-thomas-corruption-gifts-propublica-ethics-congress)**
- The Guardian, **[The US supreme court has hijacked American democracy US supreme court has hijacked American democracy](https://www.theguardian.com/commentisfree/2023/jul/11/supreme-court-republican-justices-shame-power-thomas-alito-roberts)**
- The Denver Post, **[The court has vastly overextended its own power and flaunted its corruption. It will take a political movement to stop them](https://www.denverpost.com/2023/09/05/us-supreme-court-impeachment-corruption-precedent/)**

> The court has vastly overextended its own power and flaunted its corruption. It will take a political movement to stop them

- AlJazeera **[The Supreme Court is so corrupt](https://www.aljazeera.com/opinions/2023/7/21/the-supreme-court-is-so-corrupt)**…it makes corruption legal.
- Senator Sheldon Whitehouse,  chairman of the Senate Judiciary committee,

Comment: -1 because the Supreme Court didn't rule climate change regulations to be illegal. They've simply ruled that such regulations must be passed by Congress.